# Python asyncio protocol race conditions

Tags: python-3.x, thread-safety, multiprocessing, race-condition, python-asyncio

Consider the following code (explanation follows):

```
import asyncio

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0
    def incr(self, data):
        self.a += 1
        print(self.a)

class GenProtocol(asyncio.SubprocessProtocol):
    def __init__(self, handler, exit_future):
        self.exit_future = exit_future
        self.handler = handler

    def pipe_data_received(self, fd, data):
        if fd == 1:
            self.handler(data)
        else:
            print('An error occurred')

    def process_exited(self):
        self.exit_future.set_result(True)

def start_proc(stdout_handler, *command):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    exit_f = asyncio.Future(loop=loop)
    subpr = loop.subprocess_exec(lambda: GenProtocol(stdout_handler, exit_f),
                                 *command,
                                 stdin=None)
    transport, protocol = loop.run_until_complete(subpr)

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def waiter(exit_future):
        yield from exit_future

    return waiter, exit_f

def main():
    my_instance = MyClass()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    waiter, exit_f = start_proc(my_instance.incr, 'bash', 'myscript.sh')
    loop.run_until_complete(waiter(exit_f))
    loop.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

A brief explanation of the componets is the following:

1. `MyClass` is very straightforward
2. `GenProtocol` is a class which allows to specify a custom handler for data received on a subprocess' stdout.
3. `start_proc` allows you to start a custom process specifying a custom handler for data received on stdout, via `GenProtocol`
4. `my_proc` is a process which runs forever, sending data to the pipe at arbitrary times

Now my question is the following: since I am using a method as handler, and since that method alters an instance attribute in a non atomic way, is this potentially dangerous? For instance, when I asynchronously receive data on the subprocess' pipe, is the handler called twice concurrently (hence risking to corrupt the data in MyClass.a) or is it serialised (i.e. the second time the handler is called it does not execute until the first is done)?

Comment: You can use sync primitives (e.g. lock) https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html

Comment: Thank you for the pointer! So the answer is that, yes, there may be race conditions, right?

Comment: See this great article about multi-threading, asynchronous programming and local reasoning in python: [Unyielding](https://glyph.twistedmatrix.com/2014/02/unyielding.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Protocol methods are regular functions, not coroutines.
They have no *yield point* inside.

So execution order is pretty straightforward: all calls are serialized, race conditions are not possible.

**UPD**

In the example `pipe_data_received()` is not a coroutine but just a function without `await` / `yield from` inside.

`asyncio` always executes it the whole at once without any context switch in the middle.

You may think that `pipe_data_received()` is protected by lock but actually no any lock is required for the case.

Locks are mandatory when you have a coroutine like this:

```
async def incr(self):
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    self.counter +=1
```

In the latter `incr()` is a coroutine and, moreover, context switch is very possible on `sleep()` call. If you want to protect parallel incrementing you may use `asyncio.Lock()`:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.counter = 0
    self._lock = asyncio.Lock()

async def incr(self):
    async with self._lock:
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
        self.counter +=1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Can you expand a bit on this or provide some external reference which gives a more detailed explanation on how this works?

Comment: I've tried to explain in  a few more words. Feel free to ask again it the answer is still not clear enough.